# Asynch component call from Java webservice

Tags: java, multithreading

We have a Java SOAP webservice which is invoked by a client application. The service needs to parse the message --> validate it and send an Acknowledgement back to the client.
Intermittently, another component should have been invoked which will perform a database transaction. 
I am thinking to use a `java.lang.Runnable` interface as part of the processing component which will perform the DB transaction asynchronously. Meantime the acknowledgement would have been sent back to the client. Below is the test code I have written. 
Can you tell if there will be any issues in case there are multiple requests invoked from client or should I add Synchronization to the block of code for DB call.

```
public class MessageProcessing implements Runnable{

private String inputMsg;

public MessageProcessing(String sampleMessage) {
    this.inputMsg = sampleMessage;
}

public void sendToSocket() {

    performDBCall();
}
private void performDBCall() {
    //TODO Code for DB Call
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Inside Child Thread");
    sendToSocket();
}
```

Comment: Every request from client will start a new MessageProcessing thread? It is not thread safe now, but synchronizing the `performDBCall()` alone won't make any difference here, you need to think and have the proper lock object to lock on. Before that, you need to decide what kind of DB operations you are doing and do they really needs to be synchronized.

Comment: @RP yes each request from client will start a new MessageProcessing thread.

Comment: Then, what kind of DB operations are you doing? If they are thread sensitive, you need to have a separate shareable monitor object and synchronize on that object. The  following link will give you some idea http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm

Answer (score 0):

From the test code that you have written, I think you should do fine without synchronization since you will be spawning a new thread for each request recieved for db transaction. However, if you are using any single instance object references within your `performDBCall` method, then you need to re-think your design. Synchronization is always a huge performance bottle neck especially in client-server architectures.

Comment: Care to explain why it's a huge performance bottle neck **especially** in client-server architectures?

Comment: For the simple reason that responses will be delayed due to synchronization and as multiple simultaneous requests keep growing in number, so will the response time. It may lead to time outs as well. "Prevention is better than cure". Therefore designing to avoid synchronization is better than just adding synchronization just because the facility exists.

Comment: Uncontested synchronization is fast, you obviously don't want to have a shared critical resource suffer from thread contention. However your answer isn't really giving any information. I won't downvote, but you're overgeneralizing things a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration but wanted to keep the answer as precise and to the point as possible OP asked if his code would have issues or not. Just wanted to ask how would you guarantee uncontested synchronization in a multi threaded model (bearing in mind a server is one) ?

Comment: I never talked about guaranteeing uncontested synchronization. It just means that if you have a shared resource that isn't critical, synchronization can be an easy and quick way to guarantee correct operation. Saying "synchronization is inherently bad" is not a useful thing to say, since people will remember it without understanding reasons.

Comment: Agree with you on that. I don't say its "inherently bad". I just advise to avoid it as much as you can in your design :)